# divs cols shuffles through php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do the task which is defined in snapshot attached here with. all i need to do this using PHP foreach loop using query, I have a single table named: categories.
please help me out.

```html
foreach($items as $item){
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  item 1 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   item 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   item 3 
  </div>
 </div>
} // end foreach loop
```

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow7o1.png)

Comment: Have you done some script so far?

Comment: nope. im totally confused. how to do it.

Comment: @McBern can you please have a loop to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$item_count = 1;
$alternate = false;

foreach($items as $item){
 if(!$alternate){
    if($item_count==1){
    echo '
    <div class="col-lg-6">'.
        $item.
    '</div>';
    }

    if($item_count==2){
    echo'
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            '.$item.'
        </div>';
    }
    if($item_count==3){
        echo'
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            '.$item.'
        </div>
    </div>';
     $item_count = 0; //reset item count here
     $alternate = true;
    } 
  }else{ //alternate item display
    if($item_count==3){
    echo '
    <div class="col-lg-6">'.
        $item.
    '</div>';
     $item_count = 0; //reset item count here
     $alternate = false;

    }

    if($item_count==1){
    echo'
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            '.$item.'
        </div>';
    }
    if($item_count==2){
        echo'
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            '.$item.'
        </div>
    </div>';
    } 
  }
  $item_count++;
} // end foreach loop
```

Answer (score 0):

For the layout that you want to implement this will help you to achieve that layout.

```
$item_count = 1;
foreach($items as $item){
    if($item_count % 2 == 0) {
    echo '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                item 1 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        item 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        item 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    else{
            echo '
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        item 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        item 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                item 1 
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    $item_count++;
} // end foreach loop
```